# Uploaded file is empty in controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to upload a file with ajax, jquery and formdata without doing a refresh.
Unfortunately, when i am trying to read the file in my controller it says that the file is empty and i have no idea why.

The div "uploadForm" is the form itself.

JQuery:

```
  $("#submitImage").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#uploadImage #submitImage').val('Uploading File..');

    var formData = new FormData($('#uploadForm'));

    $.ajax({
        url: "Upload",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });


});
```

Html:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id="uploadForm"}))
        {
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" id="submitImage"/>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="bannerImage" value="Choose file" />
    }
```

Controller:

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        Functions Functions = new Functions();
        string Filename = Functions.GenerateUniqueFileName();

        if (file == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Test = "Ajax call complete, but the file is empty";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Test = "Ajax call complete, and the file isn't empty!";
        }
        return View();
    }

}
```

Live demo: http://upload.jamieknoef.nl/ (You only need to use the choose file & upload file buttons)

**Edit: Fixed, see my other post for the answer!**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you try passing the data in ajax call in json format like this. `var fileName=$('#bannerImage').val();   $.ajax({ data:{flName:fileName  } } );`

Comment: I don't know what that "FormData" thing is, but you can't upload files via plain jQuery `$.ajax()` like that.

Comment: @dreamweiver, this doesn't work unfortunately.
Pointy, it's possible with with html 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know why it works with the second chunk of code you posted, this is why:

On the first chunk you had

```
var formData = new FormData($('#uploadForm'));
```

Where you are passing the jQuery wrapped object to the FormData constructor. This won't work because the constructor expects a HTMLFormElement  (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FFormData).

In the second chunk you have:

```
var form = $(this);    
formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
```

Which works as expected because form[0] is the actual DOM element representing the form.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what the problem was, but i found this code that does work:

```
$('#myform').on('sumbit', function(){
var form = $(this);
var formdata = false;
if (window.FormData){
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
}

var formAction = form.attr('action');
$.ajax({
    url         : '/upload',
    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
    cache       : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    type        : 'POST',
    success     : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Callback code
    }
});
```

});

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/p-n7eq